# Remote notifications from background

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, apn

I am creating an app in swift which will use `UNNotificationAction` buttons.

I have `userNotificationCenter` set up properly and I can call `didReceive` properly while the app is open... From here I show a modal window.

The issue is that when the app is not running in foreground or background (user hasn't opened app yet) I can't get `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to parse my code when I check on `launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification]`

Is there a new technique for processing when a user fresh opens the app when tapping on a push notification using a `UNNotificationAction`?

Answer (score 0):

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, when you discover that you are launching because of a notification, set yourself as the UNUserNotificationCenter's `delegate` and return `false`. Now your `didReceive` implementation will be called.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't seem to get it to trigger though, I have added return false in my check on remote notifications. No luck.

Comment: Scratch that.. It looks like when I tap on the push notification it works just fine, but when I tap the action item UNNotificationAction "Snooze" in my case, it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Check this code below , Hope this helps.

```
     @UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }



   @available(iOS 10, *)

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
     Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // print(userInfo)
      completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
   // completionHandler([])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    switch response.actionIdentifier {
    case "action1":
        print("Action First Tapped")
    case "action2":
        print("Action Second Tapped")
    default:
        break
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not my issue. My issue is that I can't hit my UNNotificationAction from when the app is closed. It works fine when the app is in the foreground, and when the app is in the background. But when the user has not opened the app at all, and it's not running, I can't hit UNNotificationAction action